# GitHub tag creation not triggering Azure pipeline

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an application, its source code is on GitHub. I created a pipeline for my application with the following triggers:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - refs/tags/*
      - feature*
```

This pipeline successfully gets triggered when I push to the remote master branch or create a tag on the master branch. But when I create a tag from the develop branch, it's not getting triggered.

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Tags need a separate trigger block:

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
```

You can have triggers defined on both branches and tags at the same time.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers), the syntax used by OP should also work

Comment: Hmm that's true... even though I never use that syntax...